# Nginx Reverse Proxy Configuration Issue with SubDomains

Tags: node.js, nginx, networking, reverse-proxy

I'm facing a perplexing problem with my Nginx setup where multiple domains are inexplicably redirecting to the same website, despite distinct server blocks being set up for each domain in the nginx configuration. I've undertaken several troubleshooting measures, such as scrutinizing configuration files, analyzing logs, and verifying DNS settings, yet I've been unable to pinpoint the underlying cause of the issue.

Details:

I'm managing two domains: treseibert.com and wanderlog.treseibert.com. Each domain should be served by separate Node.js applications operating on different ports (3001 and 3000, respectively). Nginx is configured to handle these domains with SSL/TLS termination and reverse proxy to their corresponding Node.js applications. However, whenever I attempt to access either domain, both end up redirecting me to the website served by the Node.js application running on port 3000.

```
    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for treseibert.com and www.treseibert.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name treseibert.com www.treseibert.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for wanderlog.treseibert.com and www.wanderlog.treseibert.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name wanderlog.treseibert.com www.wanderlog.treseibert.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server block for treseibert.com and www.treseibert.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name treseibert.com www.treseibert.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key1.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # Additional SSL settings can be added here if needed
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

# HTTPS server block for wanderlog.treseibert.com and www.wanderlog.treseibert.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name wanderlog.treseibert.com www.wanderlog.treseibert.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key1.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # Additional SSL settings can be added here if needed
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Steps Taken:

Checked Nginx configuration files (/etc/nginx/sites-available) for syntax errors and accuracy.
Verified DNS settings to ensure proper mapping of each domain to the correct server IP address.
Checked Nginx error and access logs (/var/log/nginx/error.log and /var/log/nginx/access.log) for any pertinent information, but found no relevant entries.
Reviewed firewall rules (ufw) to confirm that traffic to essential ports (80 and 443) is permitted.
Investigated network configuration (ifconfig and ip addr show) to validate correct network settings.
Ensured absence of conflicting entries in the /etc/hosts file.
Temporarily disabled SSL configuration in Nginx to observe its impact on behavior, but the issue persisted.
Altered the port in one of the server blocks to ascertain if the problem relates to port configuration, but observed no change in behavior.
Moreover, there are no error logs from nginx.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to further troubleshoot and resolve this predicament. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: This looks more like a [sf] question than a _programming_ one.  I see no program here.